# Fetching images from SD Card and displaying in Gridview

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-gridview

I am attempting to fetch all the images from the SD Card and display them in a gridview (contained in a fragment). However, although no exceptions are thrown, nothing is displayed in the gridview, just a plain black screen. I'm not sure where the problem is, with the binding of the view or with the fetching of the data into the cursor. This is the current code for the fragment:

```
public class PhotoGridFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

// member variables for
private static final int PHOTO_LIST_LOADER = 0x01;
private ImageCursorAdapter adapter;
private Cursor c;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(PHOTO_LIST_LOADER, null, this);

    adapter = new ImageCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), c);
}

/* R.layout.grid_item,
null, new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA }, new int[] {R.id.grid_item},
CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER); */

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, container, false);     
}


// Loader manager methods
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}

private class ImageCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView newView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.layout.grid_item);
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
        if (imagePath != null && imagePath.length() != 0 && newView != null) {
            newView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        return v;
    }


}
```

The layout files for the project are as follows:

photo_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/photo_item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="24dp"
android:padding="6dp" />
```

grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_item"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="24dp"
android:padding="6dp"

/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bindView, you're not actually setting the imageView's drawable to anything.  You grab an image path, verify it's a real path, and then ignore it :)  Use the path to get a drawable!  Then set the imageView's drawable to that image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

sdcard.java

```
public class Sdcard extends Activity {

//  Cursor used to access the results from querying for images on the SD card.

private Cursor cursor;

 // Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.

private int columnIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdcard);

    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


}

private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
        context = localContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView picturesView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            picturesView = new ImageView(context);
            // Move cursor to current position
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
            picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            picturesView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }
        else {
            picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }
        return picturesView;
    }
}
```

}